# Change default font in sphinx documentation

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to change the default font in sphinx documentation. I'm using the sphinx_bootstrap_theme 'journal'

How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create your own "`_templates`" directory and "`layout.html`" file (assuming you build from a "source" directory):

```
$ mkdir source/_templates
$ touch source/_templates/layout.html
```

Configure your "conf.py":

```
templates_path = ['_templates']
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

Override file "`source/_templates/layout.html`":

```
{# Import the theme's layout. #}
{% extends "!layout.html" %}

{# Custom CSS overrides #}
{% set bootswatch_css_custom = ['_static/my-styles.css'] %}
```

In `_static/my-styles.css`:

```
body{
    font-family:"Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

[This link](https://github.com/ryan-roemer/sphinx-bootstrap-theme#adding-custom-css) should further be useful

Answer (score 3):

I found a simpler way to do the same thing.

1. Create a CSS file under _static folder. for ex, `_static/css-style.css`
2. Add the name of the CSS file in conf.py

```
## conf.py

html_css_files = [
    'css/css-style.css',
]
```

In _static/css-style.css:

```
body{
    font-family:"Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Reference:
https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/adding-custom-css.html